# How to add theme to an existing live website

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have recently migrated using Wordpress One Click Install from DreamHost…The Wordpress Website Builder was also installed in the process. I have selected and activated a theme on Wordpress but when I try to customize it shows my website’s home page, not the preview I saw on the theme I want to change my website to… On the left panel I can confirm that the theme I want to use is “active” and on the top right of the panel the changes have been “published” but the website doesn’t have any visible changes. Any Ideas on how I can get a theme to work on my current active website?

Comment: This might be get more attention over at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com. It's not programming related and is very specific to Wordpress. You *may* want to try refreshing your web page while holding your shift key. This forces most browsers to bypass their cache and reload everything from the website it's pointed at.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about "wordpress.stackexchange.com" sorry to bother you guys.

Comment: No worries. Mazwi. It's no bother. I hope you find the help you are looking for. It sounds frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen any cache plugin on the website or a cache set up on the server setting? If yes you can clear cache and after that please check.

Comment: Fantastic I deactivated the cache plugin and re-activated it after a couple of minutes, the theme is now visible! Thank you!